# Q: How can I import a table from IAAI site to google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a website link which is this
https://www.iaai.com/saleslist/711/09032021
and I am trying to import all the info in this webpage using
=importxml("https://www.iaai.com/saleslist/711/09032021","/html/body/section/main/section[3]/div/div/div[1]/section[2]/div/table")
but it does not work.
I know I am learning basic stuff and at the very beginning.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a table, the syntax is

```
=importhtml("https://www.iaai.com/saleslist/711/09032021","table",1)
```

But in this case, you will be above max authorized size. You then need a script:

```
function importTableHTML(url) {
  var html = '<table' + UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").match(/(?<=\<table).*(?=\<\/table)/g) + '</table>';
  var trs = [...html.matchAll(/<tr[\s\S\w]+?<\/tr>/g)];
  var data = [];
  for (var i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
    var tds = [...trs[i][0].matchAll(/<(td)[\s\S\w]+?<\/(td)>/g)];
    var prov = [];
    for (var j=0;j<tds.length;j++){
      donnee=tds[j][0];
      prov.push(stripTags(donnee.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gm," ")));
    }
    data.push(prov);
  }
  return(data);
}

function stripTags(body) {
  var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
  return body.replace(regex,"");
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yb4Zc3gsBbnM9FD-T_vU6YivVJuMlaJJTnMAOCtwy3M/copy

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my problem. Thank you for your time and dedication.
I working now on learning python to understand how programming work. Do you have any advice for improving my programming skills for example (How can I develop scripts for google sheets and so on ) 
Thank you.

Comment: Programming for me is just experience and skill, like coming here to understand how somebody solved a question. I don't know python yet ... but I am working on sonn.

Comment: Thank you my brother